# Pixel difference between illustrator and photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, pixel, pixel-art, pixel-grid

I'm starting to learn pixel art and I have a problem when I try to use sprite sheet for reference.

I have this sprite sheet in Photoshop, and I select the pointed area:

[image]

Problem is when I paste it in Illustrator. I create a file with pixel proportions of selected image (32x34 in this case). I create a layer and I put a Rectangle Grid. Then, pixels does not match perfectly (as I wish) with the image pasted. Like this:

[image]

Notice that it's a little difference between pixels of 1st picture (Image for sprite sheet downloaded and opened with Photoshop) than the 2nd picture (selected area pasted in Illustrator).

What is the problem? How could I get a perfect pixel match between the 1st and 2nd pictures?

Comment: Your Illustrator grid is 33 high and should be 34-

Comment: It's not the problem, maybe I made a mistake puting 33. Problem is that squares of grid are a little bit smaller than character picture pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that your character pixels are smaller than your Illustrator grid. Illustrator has no concern for your imported pictures individual pixel size.

Just select your imported Photoshop image in the layers panel and resize it to fit your Illustrator grid. You can do this by math in the Transform Panel. Probably more simply you can show the bounding box (View> Show Bounding Box) and Shift+ Drag from one of the corners of the image (Shift will keep the image proportions correct).

You just need to align the image pixel size to your grid size.

Otherwise you must create your Photoshop document at 32 px by 34 px (or whatever size you want) and **make sure it is set to 72 pixels per inch in the resolution**. Then create your Illustrator document to be the exact same dimension in pixels as your Photoshop document and create your grid on top- then things will line up correctly for you. Illustrator's drawing space for vector graphics is 72 pixels per inch.

Comment: Yah, that's the solution. And nice information text. Thank you! :)